# Silverlight - Get the ItemsControl of a DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that is using a DataGrid. Inside of that DataGrid I have a DataTemplate that is defined like the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Tag="{Binding}" Loaded="myGrid_Loaded">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" Tag="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="138">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged" />
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

When a user enters text into the TextBox, I have an event (myTextBox_TextChanged) that must be fired at this point. When that event gets fired, I would like to get the ItemsControl element that is the container for this TextBox. How do I get that ItemsControl from my event handler?

Please note: Because the ItemsControl is in the DataTemplate of DataGrid, I don't believe I can just add an x:Name and reference it from my code-behind. Or is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell my why you need a reference to the ItemsControl I sense there may be a better overall solution hidden here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of `ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer` and `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` you should be able to find your ItemsControl

```
var txt = sender as TextBox;
var panel1 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(txt);
var panel2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(panel1);
var contentPresenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(panel2);
var ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(contentPresenter);
```

You may also want search the web for VisualTreeHelper Recursive functions to make some of this easier.

Answer (score 4):

I like to have this little extension method in a static class somewhere in my app:-

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Ancestors(this DependencyObject root)
{
    DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
    while (current != null)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
}
```

With that you should be able to do something like this:-

```
ItemsControl control = ((DependencyObject)sender).Ancestors()
    .TypeOf<ItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Stumbled upon this after tons of searching around.  I was trying to figure out how to update a second ComboBox in a row when the first ComboBox index changed.  This will make it easy for me to find the parent DataGridRow and subsequently the second ComboBox in the same row.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies but this creates a "toggling button bar" using the same principles.

```
private void UIClassButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
 Button SenderButton = (Button)sender;
 ItemsControl SendersItemControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(SenderButton));
 IEnumerable<DependencyObject> DependencyObjectCollection = SendersItemControl.GetContainers();

foreach (ContentPresenter item in DependencyObjectCollection) {
    ContentPresenter UIClassPresenter = (ContentPresenter)item;
    Button UIClassButton = (Button)UIClassPresenter.GetVisualChildren().First();
    if (UIClassButton != SenderButton) {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(UIClassButton, "Normal", true);
    }
    else {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(UIClassButton, "Pressed", true);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of capturing a container that houses your ItemsControl's item:

```
       CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

        foreach (var item in MembersItemsControl.Items)
        {
            var container = MembersItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;

            UserInformation user = container.DataContext as UserInformation;

            bool isMale = true;
            if (user.sex == isMale && checkbox.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                container.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

I hope that helps.