# Silverlight ItemsControl behavior: how do i get an item i click on?

Tags: c#, silverlight, itemscontrol, behavior

I'm creating a behavior for an ItemsControl with the purpose of selecting the item i click on (and adding it to a list of selected items).

So it's easy to get all the items:

```
hours = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as List<Hour>;
```

and of course i could write hours[0].Selected = true;

but then I've got a mouse event, that i tried writing something like this:

```
void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        hour = sender as Hour;
    }
```

the problem is, it's not working like i expected... the sender is not an Hour, it's an ItemsControl.

and I've got no indication as to which hour was clicked.
so what should i do to get the hour?

**Edit**
My code works like this:
there's an ItemsControl bound to a list of Days.
each day has a list of hours.
and to represent that, there is an inner ItemControl bound to (day.)Hours.
and to represent each hour, there's a border.

looks like this:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="daysPanel" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="dayHours" ItemsSource="{Binding Hours}" Grid.Row="1">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                  <Border Name="dayHourBorder" Tag="{Binding}" Height="30" BorderBrush="#B0B6BE" Width="193" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{Binding Path=Selected, Converter={StaticResource boolToColorConverter}}" >
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thanks everyone for trying to help, but i found the right way to do it.
i knew there had to be simple way to get the UI element that was clicked on, there just had to be one!

and there was!
instead of working with the sender, you just have to do:
e.OriginalSource

that got me the border (and the hour that's bounded to it).
so it's as "simple" as:

```
(e.OriginalSource as Border).DataContext as Hour
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! If you have multiple elements nested in the Border, then one should use this: (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Hour; - Otherwise there can be problems when casting.

Answer (score 1):

[VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838402(v=VS.95).aspx) may be useful for you.
You can use to get all elements at point, where mouse clicked and get your Border. Its tag is binded to Hours, so you can get it.
[Get the ItemsControl of a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348209/silverlight-get-the-itemscontrol-of-a-datatemplate) from SO and [VisualTreeHelper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kmahone/archive/2009/03/29/visualtreehelper.aspx) from http://blogs.msdn.com must help you.

Comment: thanks, but there is a much easier way, and i found it, gonna post it now

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work - the sender will be the UI element that sent the click event, and since you're using ItemsSource to set it up, each item's DataContext will be what you're after:

```
hour = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Hour
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only gives me the a list of all the hours, and that's because it actually gives me a "Day" object. (each day is a list of 24 hours).
So in short, this still doesn't give me an indication of which hour i clicked on =/

Comment: Maybe I missed something - can you show how you're loading the ItemsControl with data and what type the data is?

Comment: I've edited the question, hope this will make it more clear.
Day and Hour are just classes I've made that hold a DateTime and an int called index. ad Hour get a DP bool called "selected"

Comment: So given you're referring to "AssociatedObject" - are you using some Expression Blend behaviors or something?  How are you hooking up to the click event at all?  I don't see any event handlers in the XAML you added.

Comment: Blend has some behaviors... but you can write your own behaviors, that's what I've done. to register to an event it's easy since you tell the behavior which control it's gonna be used on. so then: AssosiciatedObject.LeftMoustButtonDown += etc. etc.
anyway, i've found the answer on my own, you can check my answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The ItemsControl by it self does not provide any properties or events for the currently selected item. You have to use a class, such as [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), that derived from ItemsControl, respectively from [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), cause this contains the functionality for item selection (SelectedItem, SelectedIndex property,...).

Comment: I know, I'm implementing them myself.
my question was how can i get the UI element that was clicked on. selection is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar to what you're doing. I wanted to make the current row the selected one.

The easiest way is to use an `ICollectionView` [MSND link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28VS.95%29.aspx) and bind THAT to the `ItemsControl`.
You can then add a behaviour (if it's not there already) that listens to the selected event and changes current accordingly.

Then you only need to hook up the `CurrentChanged` event on your ViewModel and you're completely decoupled from the UI :)

Let me know if it's what you're looking after and I may try and get some of my code as an example.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm doing, i'm asking how to get the UI Element that i clicked on, and i'm positive that's it's possible.